# Method for distributing items to multiple parties based on stack-ranked list?

Tags: list, math, optimization, ranking

This is more of a Math questions, maybe, but I'm curious if anyone has any leads.
I have a list of objects, let's say A-G. I have a list of parties, say P1-P5. Each party comes up with a list of objects in a priority order. So, let's say:

- P1: C>D>B>G>A>F>E
- P2: F>D>C>E>A>G>B
- P3: A>B>C>D>E>F>G
- P4: C>D>G>B>E>F>A

In reality, there's more parties and more objects than this, but simplifying.

Is there a way to optimize "When we acquire Object X, it should go to Party Y first"? I want to build a system that takes input objects, in a randomized order, and figures out which party to distribute it to such that an optimized order is built so that each party gets as close to their prioritized list in order as possible.

This seems like something that exists that I just don't know the name for, some kind of ranking algorithm, but any leads anyone has I would appreciate! Language agnostic.

Few additional details: The objects can appear in any order, and it's possible that a single object appears multiple times before every object has appeared. But once a party has an object, it doesn't need another. The goal is to come up with something that says, before any object appears, "If Object A appears, it goes to party X. If object B appears, it goes to...". Such that every party is getting at least one object and each party is getting as close to their optimized list as possible, updated as objects appear.

The more I type here the more specific this feels and like there may not be a pre-existing answer out there, but it just feels like the details are making me miss some existing optimization algo that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be easy enough to add a "Preferred Party" or similar piece of metadata to the object. Then as you iterate objects you can identify the preferred party for that object and if it is full you can go to the second preferred party, then third, and so on.